# Problem using a comma in a Google Analytics API filter

Tags: regex, api, filter, escaping, google-analytics

I am having an issue with the [Google Analytics Query Explorer](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/gdataExplorer.html) when I try to provide a filter with a regexp that contains a comma. I know that [commas must be escaped](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/gdataReferenceDataFeed.html#filters), but even if I add a blackslash before in the explorer, it does not work.

Example of working filter : **ga:pagePath=~^/boutique-p\d{4}**

Example of NOT working filter : **ga:pagePath=~^/boutique-p\d{1,4}**

The second example should in theory be more loose and return more results, but it doesn't.

I also tried backslash before comma, non-greedy regexp, still nothing.

Any clue ?

Comment: Did you try `...-p\d\d?\d?\d?` or just `-p\d` (and `-p\d\d` etc) to make sure your dataset actually contains shorter values?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is still a bit confusing on the google page (after 2 years).

Your not working sample should be encoded in this way:

```
ga%3ApagePath%3D~%5E%2Fboutique-p%5Cd%7B1%2C4%7D
```

I usually use this website to figure out encoded/decoded strings:

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/

Using the http://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/

You can see how it is encoded clicking on the first icon top-left (the one with the world)

Answer (score 0):

The comma is a reserved character (it is used to separate filter expressions. If you want to include it in the expression, it must be escaped with a backslash \,

per: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#filters  section labelled Filter Expressions - Reserved Characters